# Two data sets with different time instances on the same ChartJs chart

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

My scenario:
A machine creates events ON, RELOAD, OFF on certain time instances.
It also sends sensor Heat data every hour, that may or may not be at time instances of events.

See sample data below.

```
events [10.30AM, 4.45PM, 6.15PM, 8PM]

Heat Data [11Am, 12PM,........., 7PM]
```

As you can see data points falls in different time ranges. Therefore, If I use example below, heat data will be totally miss aligned.

https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/time/line-point-data.html

Is there a way to plot these two datasets accurately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply define your [data as points](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#input-data) through an array of objects that have an `x` and an `y` property each.

```
data: [{
    x: new Date(),
    y: 1
}, {
    t: new Date(),
    y: 10
}]
```

> Make sure to **not** define `data.labels` in this case.